Replacing old bathtub faucet
I apologize in an advanced for my lack of knowledge on this. I’ve never had to fix a bathtub faucet before.
My bathtub faucet has excessive leaking whenever I use the shower. I thought it might have been getting larger deposits of minerals and things that were blocking the diverter so I soaked it in white vinegar for about 20 minutes and used an old tooth brush to scrub it as best as I could, then thoroughly rinsed it out. This did not resolve the issue so I just decided to buy a new faucet, New faucet is also a slip-on.
I removed the old faucet again and realized that all of the videos I watched online did not have this plastic piece at the end of the copper pipe. Not sure what this piece is but I’m not sure it’s supposed to be installed when I install my new faucet. If I’m supposed to remove this, how can I do it? If not, how should I install the faucet?

Plastic piece at the end of the copper pipe.

New faucet

Old faucet

That plastic piece is the old "guts" from your old slip-on tub spout. Spray it with penetrating lube and pull it off by hand (use wrench to pull off whilst also twisting, if you must).

The plastic fitting remaining can be threaded on or slipped on with internal O- rings.
Either method will require turning in a counterclockwise direction. This will unscrew the fitting if it is screwed on or break the O-ring seal if it is slipped on. Spray a little oil internally first.  Use a pair of slip-lock pliers if you have them. Do not squeeze too tightly so you don't damage the pipe.
Unscrew a few turns and pull the fitting will eventually come off.
